# Docker-compose adding ADD and ENTRYPOINT instead of dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a dockerfile and I would like to move the ADD and ENTRYPOINT commands to the docker-compose file, is that possible?If yes how?

```
FROM eclipse-temurin:19-jdk-alpine
RUN apk add --no-cache maven
VOLUME /tmp
ADD . . 
ADD /target/menu-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app.jar"]

EXPOSE 5000
```

docker-compose:

```
version: "3"
services:
 web:
  build:
   context: .
   dockerfile: Dockerfile
   ports:
      - "80:8080"
```

Comment: ADD, no. ENTRYPOINT, yes. See https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#entrypoint

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I would like to keep the docker file with no ADD because I sue it also on gitlab CI where it is not needed and cause errors @Paolo . So I need the add only locally where I use docker-compose

Comment: `ADD` (or better `COPY`) is a really core part of building images and your CI system absolutely should be able to handle it.  I might clean up your Dockerfile a little bit but I'd definitely prefer the current setup to providing the command only as a runtime option.

Answer (score -1):

After a bit of trial and error phase I found that the ADD statement in dockerfile can be equivalent to volumes and the entrypoint can be changed as command in docker-compose, below my solution:

```
version: "3"
services:
 web:
  build:
   context: .
   dockerfile: Dockerfile
  volumes:
   - ./target/:/tmp
  command: ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","tmp/menu-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
  ports:
   - "80:8080"
```

Comment: What's left in your image?  This seems like you've reduced the Compose setup to injecting a jar file into a plain-Java image, which in turn is basically equivalent to just running `java -jar ...` on your host system without Docker.